# "This were all" or "all this were" a dream

Tags: adverbs, sentence-structure

Which is correct or more common:

> I wish
>
> - this were all a dream
> - this all were a dream
> - all this were a dream

Answer (score 0):

The examples have slightly different meanings.

> I wish this were all a dream.

Means "I wish [this particular thing] were *just* a dream". It uses the stock phrase, "all a dream" which means "just a dream".

> I wish this all were a dream.
>
> I wish all this were a dream.

Mean "I wish [all of these things] were a dream". To my ears as a native speaker they are interchangeable with the former being slightly more common.

The first example is probably the most commonly used. We might use the latter two to emphasize that we are talking about many things.

In fact, I would argue that

> I wish this all were all a dream.

would be a plausible sentence if you want to be clear that you are talking about many things, and you want to employ the stock phrase.

Comment: To *my* ears as a native speaker, the position of ***all*** in *I wish this all were a dream* sounds extremely unusual. As [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wish+this+all+was%2Cwish+all+this+was%2Cwish+this+all+were%2Cwish+all+this+were&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwish%20all%20this%20was%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwish%20all%20this%20were%3B%2Cc0) shows, the modern trend is to dump that stuffy subjunctive ***were*** in favour of ***was*** anyway, but your sequence doesn't occur often enough to chart whichever verb form it is.